Firebase FCM - Error sending notifications
I deployed function but in log I see this message. My serviceAccount.json file is inside function folder and linked properly.
"Error sending notifications: FirebaseMessagingError: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: ""


I checked on web but not able to find solution. please advise. enter image description here

Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767439/an-error-occurred-when-trying-to-authenticate-to-the-fcm-servers

Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code
